# How to use magneticHeading in Swift?

Tags: swift, rotation, imageview, compass

I'm trying to make a simple by feet navigator, using a arrow image, rotating to indicate the direction to follow with a constant refresh.

Using `magneticHeading` i found error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, maybe i forgot something.

How i can use correctly magneticHeading?

```
var northLatitude :CLLocationDegrees 
var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = 46.0
var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = 7.0


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    longitude = manager.location.coordinate.longitude
    latitude = manager.location.coordinate.latitude

    var buildingLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var regionOfInterest:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(buildingLocation, span)

    self.mapView.setRegion(regionOfInterest, animated: true)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(buildingAnnotation)

    northLatitude = manager.heading.magneticHeading  //ERROR
}
```

Comment: please ask a proper question and show us what work you have done and where you are stuck. that is the only way we can help you out.

Comment: the question is: how i can make an image view (constantly refresh) pointing to coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the angle at which the arrow should point and then use the transform property of the image view to change direction. Pseudo code will be something like this.

```
func onPositionChange()
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:
        {
            var angle_in_degrees:CGFloat = 10 // Calculated Angle.
            var angle_in_radians = (angle_in_degrees * 3.1415) / 180.0
            self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle_in_radians)
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, with this function i have a problem. the image view (a square with an arrow in the top center) rotate for a wrong angle.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8055fin5prhfv6/arrow.png?dl=0

this is 90degrees for the simulator

Comment: how are you calculating the angle? in degrees or radians?

Comment: degrees... how i can calculate radians?

Comment: I have modified my answer with the calculation. check it out.